# how to list all the methods available for a given object in ruby but not the inbuilt ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do i list all the methods of an object in Ruby which are not in-built methods,
if I do Fruit.new.methods it will list all the methods which includes user defined methods which are declared in the class Fruit,I want to see only the methods which are written in class Fruit.

Answer (score 3):

`myFruit.public_methods(false)` returns the list of public methods accessible to `myFruit` with inherited methods excluded.

Comment: You can also do `Fruit.instance_methods(false)` to see all instance methods of that particular class.

Comment: @osahyoun it works perfectly fine with ruby but if i do same thing with in rails class(ie some controller calss) how do i extract in that case.